# C# How to get triggers information

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

How to get triggers information from the `TaskService` object for the scheduled tasks?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
TaskService st = new TaskService();
var tasks = st.RootFolder.GetTasks();
foreach (Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task task in tasks)
{ 
     sb.Append(task.Name+",");
     sb.Append(task.someValueHere <<<--- 
     sb.Append(task.LastRunTime + ",");
     sb.Append(task.NextRunTime.ToString()+" ; ");
}          
st.Dispose();
```

Comment: You probably need to access the `TaskDefinition` and from there the `Triggers` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `Definition` and then the `Triggers`. For example:

```
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    //...
    foreach (var trigger in task.Definition.Triggers)
    {
        //...access trigger properties here.
    }
}
```